# Magento: Add multiple products to cart at once

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I have a number of configurable products in Magento CE 1.9

I would like to give users the ability to view a product and add multiple sizes to their cart with one click .

---

```
Product Title

Small : Select Quantity
Medium: Select Quantity
Large: Select Quantity
```

Add to Cart

---

The cart would then need to show how many of each size has been selected and show the total cost for that product.

Is this doable, and what is the best approach?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do it but it would be a lot of information for your customer, so what in my experience solves best you problem is to use an ajax cart module, that can add products to cart without leaving the pages, so if the customer want many sizes or colors, he keep adding the one he want.

Here follow a module that is already developed, but if you want a custom development my company can do for you just get in contact with me. ( [module:](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ajax-cart-5.html)  <---- not my company module but worked once with a customer)

Comment: It's a facility that is offered on many business to business websites for wholesale e.g. Brandboom. 

It's not too much information for these users - it's a requested feature. I'm afraid your ajax cart suggestion wouldn't be an appropriate soltion. 

They want to be able to add e.g. 3Small, 2medium and 1 large to the cart by clicking the add to cart button once.

Comment: Ok so you could do a code like one of my customers but its really complex one se some products that have it at: [4vets.com.br](http://4vets.com.br)

Comment: create Bundle product for this.